# Devise admin routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a devise User and inside I have admin as boolean default to false. How can I fixed my routes in my ruby on rails app for it to give access to certain pages ONLY for the admin who has admin as true.

UPDATE:
I changed followed the first answer I got which said to create a is_admin? method in my controller and specify what actions. However, when I do that, I get a:

```
undefined method `admin' for nil:NilClass
```

UPDATE 2:

Products Controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :is_admin?, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show]
```

Application Controller:

```
def is_admin?
  if signed_in?
    redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin
  end
end
```

Comment: to eliminate your undefined method error change `current_user.admin` to `current_user.try(:admin)` It appears that your `signed_in?` method doesn't check for the presence of current_user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't do that in the routes file, the best place to do it's on the controller filtering part. Attention to the `:authenticate_user!` method being before the is_admin?. Otherwise `current_user` will be nil.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!
   before_action :is_admin?, only: [:action1, :action2]
   ...
  
   private
   
   def is_admin?
     unless current_user.is_admin?
       flash.alert = "Sorry, you don't have permissions to perform this action."
       redirect_to root_path
     end
   end
end
```

Comment: I get undefined method 'admin' for nil:NillClass when the user is not the admin

Comment: put `is_admin?` in `ApplicationController` for use on another controller if needed, and add `user_signed_in?` condition for check user signed or not.

Comment: @ZehniKhairullah show your code and full stack trace now on your question, so we will check them.

Comment: @anonymousxxx I did it

Comment: Check edited answer, you have to add default devise authenticate method.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) gem and policies for everything related to authorizations.